# Deal with multiple tables to export mysql db data to xml

Tags: php, mysql, xml, domdocument

I need help by explaining with the code so I can understand how to deal with multiple tables:

there are a several tables called

> apartments, properties, categories, developers

1. apartments columns (id, category_id, developer_id, property_id,
   title, price)
2. categories columns (id, title)
3. developers columns (id, title)
4. properties columns (id, title, category_id)

the relation between them as following:

- `category_id` synced with `id` column in `categories` table
- `developer_id` synced with `id` column in `developers` table
- `property_id` synced with `id` column in `properties` table

and I need to update the below php code to make the output like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<list>  
    <property>
        <title>apartments_title</title >
        <price>apartments_price</price >
        <type>properties_title</type>
        <categoty>categories_title</categoty>
        <developer>developer_title</developer>
   </property>

</list>
```

I using this code to retrieve the data from one table

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');

// INITIALIZE DOM OBJECT
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->formatOutput = true;            
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// CREATE ROOT AND APPEND TO DOCUMENT
$xmlRoot = $dom->createElement("list");
$xmlRoot = $dom->appendChild($xmlRoot);

// QUERY DATABASE
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=dbname','dbusername','password');
$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from apartments");
$stmt->execute();

// FETCH ROWS ITERATIVELY
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
     // APPEND property AS CHILD OF ROOT
     $propertyNode = $xmlRoot->appendChild($dom->createElement('property'));

     // APPEND CHILDREN TO Property         
     $propertyNode->appendChild($dom->createElement('title', $row['title']));
     $propertyNode->appendChild($dom->createElement('price', $row['price']));
}
$stmt = null; 
$db = null;

// OUTPUT TO SCREEN
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: Rather than doing a query for each row in apartments, just use a SQL join to the other tables and do one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you want to use a join to get the values you want. A left join ensures that all records from the apartments table are included, while missing values from the other tables (if any) will be returned as NULL.

```
SELECT a.title AS title, a.price AS price, p.title AS type,
    c.title AS category, d.title AS developer
FROM apartments a
LEFT JOIN properties p ON (a.property_id = p.id)
LEFT JOIN categories c ON (a.category_id = c.id)
LEFT JOIN developers d ON (a.developer_id = d.id);
```

Notice I've set aliases for the tables (to make the SQL cleaner) and also for the columns, to use when building the XML. You can just loop over the result instead of calling `createElement` separately for each column. This is possible because I've specified the fetch type as an associative array instead of the default fetch type, which is both associative and numeric. One final note, you don't need to `prepare()` and `execute()` a statement if there are no parameters. Simply running `query()` will give you the same result.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');

// INITIALIZE DOM OBJECT
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->formatOutput = true;            
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// CREATE ROOT AND APPEND TO DOCUMENT
$xmlRoot = $dom->createElement("list");
$xmlRoot = $dom->appendChild($xmlRoot);

// QUERY DATABASE
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=dbname','dbusername','password');
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT a.title AS title, a.price AS price, p.title AS type, c.title AS category, d.title AS developer FROM apartments a LEFT JOIN properties p ON (a.property_id = p.id) LEFT JOIN categories c ON (a.category_id = c.id) LEFT JOIN developers d ON (a.developer_id = d.id);");

// FETCH ROWS ITERATIVELY
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    // APPEND property AS CHILD OF ROOT
    $propertyNode = $xmlRoot->appendChild($dom->createElement('property'));
    foreach ($row as $element=>$value) {
        // APPEND CHILDREN TO Property         
        $propertyNode->appendChild($dom->createElement($element, $value));
    }
}

// OUTPUT TO SCREEN
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

If you are feeding this data to a service of your own, you may want to consider JSON instead of XML. JSON's simpler data structure and PHP's very concise built-in functions would make this a much smaller program:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');    

// QUERY DATABASE
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=dbname','dbusername','password');
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT a.title AS title, a.price AS price, p.title AS type, c.title AS category, d.title AS developer FROM apartments a LEFT JOIN properties p ON (a.property_id = p.id) LEFT JOIN categories c ON (a.category_id = c.id) LEFT JOIN developers d ON (a.developer_id = d.id);");

// FETCH ROWS
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

// OUTPUT TO SCREEN
echo json_encode($rows);
```